# Я тебЯ посмеюсь

Tags: падежи, местоимения

Всегда слышал фразу из сабжа только через "е". Но мне сказали, что говорят через "я" и не мало. Кто-нибудь знает о такой форме (литературной нету скорее всего, речь скорее про произношение именно) и откуда она взялась / где распространена?

Comment: Я понимаю, что грамотного варианта такого нету. В словарях не находится. Но интересна история "неграмотно-народной" формы и где она конкретно используется таки

Answer (score 2):

Если такая форма и существует, то только на каком-нибудь диалекте. или может быть, какой-то малограмотный так сказал, и такой же малограмотный утверждает, что так говорят.

Answer (score 2):

Это, видимо, из той же серии, как известная  стебовая фраза "кто девушку угощает, тот ее и танцует"